# getting default value to display when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a default value to display when the page loads.

I am trying to get the first button to always show by default in the display-donation div whenever someone navigates to the form.

At the moment, this is what it looks like when the page loads. 10 is highlighted but does not display.

[image]

Here is my html

```
      <div class="btn-group">
              <div class="buttons">
                <button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color active" value="10">10</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="15">15</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="20">20</button>
                <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
              </div>
 <div class="money-donate">
            <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
      $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
      });
     $( ".selectvalue" ).click(function() {
        $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
     });

    $(".buttons .btn").click(function(){
        $(".buttons .btn").removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
    });
});
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to show the amount auto selected/active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently asking for the value attribute of the display-amount div, which of course doesn't exist. You want something like `$('#display-amount').text($('.active').val());` instead.

Comment: Thank you!! I changed .active to the id and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this - change line 3 to:

```
$('#display-amount').text($('button.active).val());
```

You need to show the `class .active` amount

Taking the amount from this:

```
<button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color active" value="10">10</button>
```